# Flutter routing 2.0 and Flutters original (1.0) we can use both at the same time?

Tags: flutter, dart

i am trying to develop depth links with flutter, and the docs says

> 'If you want to implement deep linking, or take advantage of multiple
> navigators, check out the 2.0 version.'

so i followed this paper to understand better this approach

https://medium.com/flutter/learning-flutters-new-navigation-and-routing-system-7c9068155ade

### but i relize that we must use

```
MaterialApp.router(
      title: 'Books App',
      routerDelegate: _routerDelegate,
      routeInformationParser: _routeInformationParser,
    );
```

### in my code

```
MaterialApp(
            localizationsDelegates: localizationsDelegates(),
            supportedLocales: supportedLocales(),
            theme: mainData(),
            initialRoute: _initialScreen,
            onGenerateRoute: (RouteSettings settings) =>
                getGeneratedRoutes(settings),
```

and MaterialApp.router won't accept these parameters `initialRoute`, `onGenerateRoute`

so i think this is not a breaking change,  we can use
MaterialApp.router and MaterialApp in the same time?

to take advantage of MaterialApp and update to routing 2.0 with time

thaks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `MaterialApp` and `MaterialApp.router` in the same app (well you can but it won't do what you probably want it to do).

However, when using `MaterialApp.router`, you can still use `Navigator.push` and `Navigator.pop`.

It's also worth mentioning that the Flutter team has a fairly strict definition of what is/isn't a breaking change: a breaking change is one that requires changes to 1 or more tests in the framework itself.

As long as, in the Flutter version that introduced `MaterialApp.router`, any tests referencing `MaterialApp` still passed, it would not be considered a breaking change.

This is not the same thing as `MaterialApp` and `MaterialApp.router` being compatible (although in this specific case they happen to be)

Answer (score 0):

I found this paper

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Q0jx0l4-xymph9O6zLaOY4d_f7YFpNWX_eGbzYxr9wY/edit#

### Coexistence of imperative and declarative AP

> As outlined above and explained in the following section the existing
> imperative API of the Navigator and the new declarative API (`possibly`
> in combination with the new Router) `can be used in parallel within the same app`

but it don't have any example. I will follow my search